# Mysql2 syntax error creating VIEW

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, bash, mysql2, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've just setup Bash on Windows 10, installed the libmysqlclient-dev package and am running a rake task that executes the below query to create a VIEW on a mysql database using ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS debtors_customer_balances;
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW debtors_customer_balances AS
  SELECT
    customer_id,
    SUM(amount_cents) AS total_cents,
    SUM(CASE
          WHEN due_on >= CURDATE()
          THEN amount_cents
          ELSE 0
          END) AS current_cents,
    SUM(CASE
          WHEN due_on >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
          AND  due_on < CURDATE()
          THEN amount_cents
          ELSE 0
          END) AS overdue7_cents,
    SUM(CASE
          WHEN due_on >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 14 DAY)
          AND  due_on < (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
          THEN amount_cents
          ELSE 0
          END) AS overdue14_cents,
    SUM(CASE
          WHEN due_on >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
          AND  due_on < (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 14 DAY)
          THEN amount_cents
          ELSE 0
          END) AS overdue30_cents,
    SUM(CASE
          WHEN due_on < (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
          THEN amount_cents
          ELSE 0
          END) AS overdue30_plus_cents
  FROM
    debtors_balances
  GROUP BY
    customer_id;
```

However, it is throwing an error

> Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW debtors_customer_balances AS   SELECT
>   ' at line 2: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS debtors_customer_balances; CREATE OR
>   REPLACE VIEW debtors_customer_balances AS   SELECT
>       customer_id, etc...

I can't figure out what's causing this as the query runs fine from a mac, it's just in bash for windows I seem to get this syntax error.

The gem I'm using is mysql2 (0.3.18)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's caused by the first line `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS debtors_customer_balances;` which actually should be `DROP VIEW ...` instead. remove that first line and it should work. Anyways, you are using `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW debtors_customer_balances` then what's the meaning of adding that `DROP` statement before?

Comment: That fixes the query so that it can run, but unfortunately the reason that DROP TABLE line is there is because this query is called at the end of the db:seed, and for some reason the VIEWS are added as TABLES to the schema, so when db:schema:load is run as part of a reseed (db:reset), it creates those views as a table and errors when it gets to this query.

Comment: Fixed the issue with VIEWS being added as TABLES in the schema by using `ActiveRecord::SchemaDumper.ignore_tables = ['debtors_customer_balances', 'debtors_customer_entity_balances']`